# Standalone Windows app hangs upon change of focus

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, windows-7

I have written an app in C++ from Visual Studio 2008, running on Windows 7, that runs fine, using either the debug or release versions, when under the control of the debugger, but when running standalone, using either the debug or release versions, it also runs fine except whenever I click on any unrelated window, say a file explorer window, whereupon the app hangs without any warnings from Windows, I see the little circle thing.

The code is doing something rather computationally intensive, accessing data from a 10Mb global array, and it is well within the 2Gb limit of 32 bit Windows.  I have checked for the obvious things, such as uninitialized variables, infinite loops, and the like, I am not allocating any big local arrays, but have found nothing wrong.  The code is running directly from the UI thread, blocking, but I do not care as there is nothing else to do till that task completes.  Alternatively, I could put this code in its own worker thread communicating back to the UI thread by an interlocked buffer, but this seems redundant.  I've tried this on two different machines running Windows 7 and get identical behavior.  Is there something about Windows process management that I am overlooking?  Is there a way to tell whether there is some sort of memory corruption going on that could cause some other process to affect the app's process?

**[Edit1 by spektre] just copied user3481340's code from comment to be readable**

- I do not think that the computational time, which is about an hour
- has anything to do with the problem.
- Rather, the windows messaging for the edit box is getting messed-up.
- The relevant code is:

  ```
  int textlen=GetWindowTextLength(Editwin);
  int k=strcspn(messagebuf,"\n");
  if(k<strlen(messagebuf))textlength=strlen(messagebuf)-k;
   else textlength+=k;
  SendMessage (Editwin, EM_SETSEL, (WPARAM)textlen, (LPARAM)textlen);
  SendMessage (Editwin, EM_REPLACESEL, 0, (LPARAM) messagebuf);
  ```
- Somehow Windows stops responding to these messages.

Comment: how long does that computation take?

Comment: Have you tried putting in any debugging statements (such as OutputDebugString) and using DebugView to monitor what your app is / isn't doing ? Maybe it hasn't hung at all ?

Comment: I did not know about DebugView.  It shows that the computational part of the code isn't hanging at all, rather, the text output is stopping.  I'm writing text to a large edit box and somehow upon clicking on another window the text stream stops.

Comment: Answer the question from AndyT. It will probably be the answer to your own question as well.

Comment: I do not think that the computational time, which is about an hour, has anything to do with the problem.  Rather, the windows messaging for the edit box is getting messed-up.  The relevant code is:     int textlen=GetWindowTextLength(Editwin);
 int k=strcspn(messagebuf,"\n");
 if(k<strlen(messagebuf))textlength=strlen(messagebuf)-k;
 else textlength+=k;
 SendMessage (Editwin, EM_SETSEL, (WPARAM)textlen, (LPARAM)textlen);
 SendMessage (Editwin, EM_REPLACESEL, 0, (LPARAM)  messagebuf);  Somehow Windows stops responding to these messages.

Answer (score 0):

Windows7 has some changes (from previous versions of windows)

1. **in process scheduling**

   which can mess up lock-less multi-thread apps which are working 100% thread safe on older versions of windows. There is not much to do with this (unless add some safety sleeps or locks)
2. **critical sections**

   I am not 100% convinced that critical sections work properly on Win7SP1 as I have some issues on specific machine setup where they do not work with combination of:

   - heavy duty USB HS bulk data transfers
   - OpenGL use
   - multi-threading with heavy multiple critical sections use

   but it could be a hidden bug or messed-up Windows7 installation or even HW error
3. **WindowProc**

   if your message loop get stuck for a longer time then it should then it will cause the program to be detected as non-responding even if it is not. Usually run in compatibility for XPSP3 helps but sadly not on all machines or all apps  :( this is the main reason why many games does not run on Win7

   **I suspect this is your case** and according to your last comment I was right.

   Transfer critical processing to some thread instead so the `WindowProc` is not blocked. If you need an event after computation is done then flag some variable as done and scan for it in some timer so you can respond inside main thread (to avoid  winapi calls outside main thread).
4. **32bit Driver+App use on x64 windows (WOW64)**

   if your app is accessing any driver then on WOW64 you need special driver build to access real hardware instead of emulated by WOW64 !!! If you did not then your App is most likely waiting for real device respond instead is getting emulated one which can be different and cause real hang ups. In that case you need compile your app as x64

   Or use some kind of WOW64.x86 -> x64 bridge

   Or use driver which can handle it itself (usually link do different dll)

Comment: Even if Windows says my app is "non-responding", shouldn't it come back once a new SendMessage() is called?  Or, is it the case that once message loop is deemed to be stuck it stays stuck?  How would moving the core computation to its own worker thread with an interlocked buffer for text output fix this (or not)?  As I said, the core computation takes awhile to run and I want to see what is going on as it goes.

Comment: you can not use winapi outside WindowProc because it mess up windows !!! after that the behavior of visual stuff get corrupted (messed up gfx, wrong texts, freezes ,incorrect timing...) when you stop windproc for longer time than its timeout (just few ms) then win7 freeze/kills your WindowProc thread !!! and will not return CPU to it !!! also you should check if that text pointers hold correct data before WinApi calls (just to be sure you do not scan ~100MB text for first zero in random data)

Comment: Could this be fixed by employing a timer to generate periodic WM_TIMER events at a period less than the timeout value?

Comment: I tried putting the long computation in its own worker thread, this works fine, but as soon as I click on any other unrelated window the app output stops, same behavior as before.  I thinking the problem is do to something other than the 5 second windows timeout.

Comment: then try to disable all parts of your program leave only GUI. then try if the problem persist ... if not then enable one by one part until your problem occurs. this way you should discover where the problem is. (can be something unrelated to winapi like memory leak or array over/under run access ...) ... without actual source code is all just guess work ...

Comment: I finally figured this out.  I was violating, what is apparently a fundamental rule of Windows programming, do not block the WndProc call-back.  I replaced the call to the function that created the worker thread with a thread of its own, and everything works fine.